# Dividing standard simplex in equal parts

Tags: permutations, simplex

Take the standard simplex $\Delta^n=\{x_1+\ldots+x_{n+1}=1,x_i\geq 0\;\forall i=1,\ldots,n+1\}$. Consider $\Delta^1$, I can divide it into two equal parts by considering the two sets $\{x\in\Delta^1:x_1<x_2\}$ and $\{x\in\Delta^1:x_1> x_2\}$. Consider $\Delta^2$, I can divide it into six equal parts by considering $\{x\in\Delta^2:x_3<x_2<x_1\}$, $\{x\in\Delta^2:x_3<x_1<x_2\}$ etc going for all the permutations on three letters (all $\sigma\in S_3$ that is). Is this true in general for any dimension? That is, is it true that I can divide $\Delta^n$ into $(n+1)!$ equal parts by using the sets $\{x\in\Delta^n:x_{\sigma(1)}<\ldots<x_{\sigma(n+1)}\}_{\sigma\in S_{n+1}}$ ? How would one prove it?

Comment: Yes, that's right (up to some quibbling about the cases when equality holds). What part are you having trouble proving?

Comment: I would like to show that these sets have all equal volume, and that it adds up to the volume of the simplex...In higher dimension the intuition fails me...

Comment: I was thinking that where equality holds we end up with lower dimensional stuff anyway so does not affect the volume in full dimension, that s why did not bother with writing equalities...

Comment: They have equal volume because they're all sent to each other under permuting the coordinates, which preserves volume. They add up to the volume of the simplex because, after ignoring the equality case, every point in the simplex is in exactly one of them. And yes, the equality cases don't affect the volume computation, but they do affect the technical statement of what it means for a collection of subsets to partition a set.

Comment: changed 'partition' in the last sentence into 'divide' just for clarity. How do you show that permuting coordinates preserves volume in this setting?

Comment: Multiplication by a matrix scales volumes by the absolute value of the determinant. For permutation matrices this is always equal to $1$. Alternatively, permutations are isometries.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, you mean the matrix of a transformation that permutes coordinates, not a 'permutation matrix'! Of course, they are elementary matrices that swap rows so their det is $\pm1$ since the identity has determinant $1$. Thank you.

Comment: That’s what “permutation matrix” means.

Comment: I was thinking of the matrix representation of a permutation in algebra, my bad....